# React Js showing Blank Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom, react-dom

I tried many different ways including having baseline on BrowserRouter and add line, initially I was using Switch but soon realised that npm 6.0 onwards has changed it to Routes, so I downgrade it to npm 5.2.3. However, a blank screen still persists.

Hope to get suggestions from the experts here

this is my App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './Home';
import {Department} from './Department';
import {Employee} from './Employee';
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';

import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename='/index.html'>
    <div className="container">
     <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
       React JS Tutorial
     </h3>

     <Navigation/>

     <Switch>
       <Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
       <Route path='/department' component={Department}/>
       <Route path='/employee' component={Employee}/>
     </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: You may want to install the latest v5. Other than this I don't see any overt issue with this code. `basename='/index.html'` doesn't seem correct, but I don't think that would cause blank pages. What version of `react` is installed? Can you provide a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this issue, try the code, it might not work but  I think you can't have any other component within BrowserRouter, hopefully that gives you at least a direction.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename='/index.html'>
     <Switch>
       <Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
       <Route path='/department' component={Department}/>
       <Route path='/employee' component={Employee}/>
     </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```